# In Angularjs should a modal be a service or a directive?

Tags: angularjs

So I have been reading about directives, services and controllers. I felt like I had a good understanding of what goes where. For example dom manipulation happens in a directive, api calls happen in a service. Then I needed to make a modal. My fist thought was this is a directive, then I looked at Angular UI and they have it set up as a service. I was surprised to see it as a service. Is this the correct way to do it, or is this considered and anti pattern? I read that Angular UI is a good place to look when learning, but I'm not sure? A modal is more confusing then I expected.﻿

Comment: I can see it is directive, where did you see it as service?

Comment: @ABOS In the [code](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js) you can see that there are 2 factories defined (including the very first thing, perhaps what the OP is thinking of?), but there are also a number of directives defined.

Comment: @ABOS Also, it actually makes sense that is is a service. You define your modal in JS code and just pass in some HTML (usually as a directive), so yeah, it is defined as a service (with helper directives).

Comment: I think those services are just helpers, but you can always argue helpers are more fundamental since directives depend on them.

Comment: @ABOS It is fundamentally a directive though. At the end of the file you can see the provider that defines `$modal`

Comment: Depends on the app but the core would be a directive. I've used my own modal service in an app to wrap around angular-ui modal in order to simplify calling a variety of different modals from different parts of the app and only needing to modify content templates. The wrapper to create modal instance cut down on a lot of code in numerous controllers

Comment: I'd go for a service: a modal is likely triggered by an event and has no specific place in the DOM. Directives are extension of the HTML where you place custom components. However nothing prevent you to design the modal in a directive and use a servcie to instanciate it.

Comment: I would also go for a service. Since you will want to call the modal on a trigger, you can chain its response right where you called it and respond to its results

Answer (score 3):

The general rule in Angular is that DOM manipulation should take place only inside directives, and most of the time that rule applies. But there are some situations where a declarative approach doesn't *feel* right, to say the least, because those situations are intrinsically imperative. Modals and custom alerts are two examples, to name a few.

To exemplify what I'm saying, take a look at this example taken from [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516024/angular-modal-dialog-best-practices) I answered some time ago:

**Imperative approach**

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $dialog) {
    $scope.doSomething = function() {
        $dialog.dialog().open().then(function(result) {
           if (result === 'OK') {
               // Process OK
           }
           else {
               // Process anything else
           }
        });
    }
});
```

*Back in the day AngularUI's `$modal` was called `$dialog`*.

**Declarative approach**

```
<dialog visible="dialogVisible" callback="dialogCallback()"></dialog>

...

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.doSomething = function() {    
        $scope.dialogVisible = true; 
    }

    $scope.dialogCallback = function(result) {
        if (result === 'OK') {
            // Process OK
        }
        else {
           // Process anything else
        }
    }
});
```

The second approach is awkward to write and it breaks the flow of the code. It's like trying to fit a square peg into a round hole.

IMO the *DOM manipulation only happens in a directive* statement is more like a (very) strong recommendation than a hard rule. It exists so people - especially newcomers to Angular - avoid accessing the DOM from within services and controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same question when I needed to refactor our code allow for more dialogs in the application. We are using Angularjs 1.6 currently.

I found that you could put a directive into each template and then use ng-show and ng-hide for displaying/hiding the modal.  However, while using directives for DOM manipulation is a convention in Angularjs, as already mentioned, in this use case a directive for modal windows creates a tight coupling between the controller and the modal directive.

Using a service in this use case is an acceptable deviation, because by using a service to inject the modal into the DOM, it is done as needed instead of the modal directive always being on the page, making this approach more dynamic and reduces the coupling with the template.

As another validation, I found that the Angular UI team uses this same approach with a modal service: [$uibModal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) to create modal windows.